# How to pickup date from long string Name column in oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have table with column 'ID', 'File_Name'
Table

```
 ID     File_Name  
 123    ROSE1234_LLDAtIInstance_03012014_04292014_190038.zip   
 456    ROSE1234_LLDAtIInstance_08012014_04292014_190038.zip
```

All I need is to pickup the first date given in file name.

Required:

```
 ID     Date  
 123    03012014
 456    08012014
```

Comment: can we assume that the 8 characters after the 2nd `_` will always be the date needed?

Comment: It confirm that 8 char after 2nd_ will be date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one method assuming 8 characters after 2nd _ is always true.

It finds the position of the first _ then looks for the position of the 2nd _ using the position of the first _+1 then it looks for the 8 characters after the 2nd _

```
SELECT Id
  , substr(File_name, instr(File_name,'_',instr(File_name,'_')+1)+1,8) as Date     
FROM Table
```

or 
a more elegant way would be to use a RegExp_Instr Function which eliminates the need for nesting instr.

```
SELECT Id, substr(File_name,REGEXP_INSTR(FileName,'_',1,2)+1,8) as date 
FROM dual;
```

Comment: I have to do same thing in Sybase. how to do in Sybase?

Comment: Based on a quick search I believe the first example would work there as well. It appears Sybase contains `substr()` and `instr()` functions.  I'm not as familiar with Sybase syntax and have no environment to test with.  So I'm not sure if RegExp_instr would be supported; though a quick search indicates not.  The first method is much more "portable" to other databases.

Answer (score 0):

Use a much simplified call to REGEXP_SUBSTR( ):

```
SQL> with tbl(ID, File_name) as (
  2    select 123, 'ROSE1234_LLDAtIInstance_03012014_04292014_190038.zip' from dual
  3    union
  4    select 456, 'ROSE1234_LLDAtIInstance_08012014_04292014_190038.zip' from dual
  5  )
  6  select ID,
  7         REGEXP_SUBSTR(File_name, '_(\d{8})_', 1, 1, NULL, 1) "Date"
  8  from tbl;

        ID Date
---------- ----------------------------------------------------
       123 03012014
       456 08012014

SQL>
```

For 11g, [click here for the parameters to REGEXP_SUBSTR( )](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm).

EDIT: Making this a virtual column would be another way to handle it.  Thanks to Epicurist's post for the idea.  The virtual column will contain a date value holding the filename date once the ID and filename are committed.  Add it like this:

```
  alter table X_TEST add (filedate date generated always as (TO_DATE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Filename, '_(\d{8})_', 1, 1, NULL, 1), 'MMDDYYYY')) virtual);
```

So now just insert the ID and Filename, commit and there's your filedate. Note that its read-only.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply put the date in separate column? E.g. you can than query the (indexed) date. The theory says the date is a property of the file. It's about avoiding errors, maintainability and so on. What in the zip files? Excel sheets I suppose :-)

Comment: And what about ISO8601 ?

Comment: Yes a virtual column would work too.  I'll update my post.

Comment: No, no, absolutely no!!! You are making it a Band-aid design. A real column at insert time brings some quality.

Comment: Whoa there cowboy.  I am simply throwing out possible alternatives.  There is not enough info or specs to determine what the best approach is for this situation, nor do we even know what changes the OP is allowed to make to the data model or process flow.  Knowing various methods will help choose the best approach.  I'm not saying any of these are the best, just different ways of getting the info asked for.  Information is power!